# Return Statement in Objective C for Binary Search Tree Search Function

Tags: objective-c

I want to write a search function for a Binary Search Tree. How can I write it so that I can return from the base case `if(root.data == node.data){return node;}` without getting compiler warnings about the method returning nothing. In this case, root is an ivar that's part of the BST class that these methods are a part of.

```
-(Node*)search:(Node*)node{
    if(root == nil){
        return node;
    }

    if(root.data == node.data){
        return node;
    }

    if (node.data < root.data){
        root = root.left;
        [self search:root];
    }

    if (node.data > root.data) {
        root = root.right;
        [self search:root];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the error because you don't return anything from your `search:` method under certain conditions. You must return something. You also don't make any use of the return value when you recursively call `search:`.

You also have a problem with updating `root`. You don't want to do that.

You probably want something more like this:

```
- (Node *)search:(Node *)node {
    if (root == nil) {
        return node;
    }

    if (root.data == node.data) {
        return node;
    } else if (node.data < root.data) {
        return [self search:node.left];
    } else // node.data > root.data
        return [self search:node.right];
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't know I could call a method in a return statement like that. Thanks.

Comment: `return` takes any valid expression. Of course you could also assign the result of `[self search:root];` to a variable and then return the variable.

Comment: but if the method returns an object (in this case node), each if statement must return an object? I can't just do return; for the first case?

Comment: @noobsmcgoobs - No you "can't just do return", when a method returns a value of any type then at each point within the body where the method can finish it must return a value. Note: you have another problem, both recursive calls pass `root` as the argument, so in those calls the parameter `node` is just a reference to `root` and you are comparing a node to itself... so one of the first two tests (`root == nil` and `root.data == node.data`) will always succeed.

Comment: @CRD Actually no. `root` is reassigned a new value before being passed.

Comment: @rmaddy - `root` is an ivar, `search` compares `root` to its argument `node`, and the recursive call is `[self search:root]`... So in that call `root` and `node` reference the same object surely? Unless I need sleep that is!

Comment: @CRD Yeah, you're right. I'm the one that misread it. I updated my answer. Thanks. Though I think there are still issues but the question was about the compiler error so I'll leave it at this.

Answer (score -1):

if none of your first two if tests are true, your method doesn't return anything. 
Try;

```
  if (node.data < root.data){
    root = root.left;
    return [self search:root];
  }

  if (node.data > root.data) {
    root = root.right;
    return [self search:root];
  }

  return ? // you need a return value here
```